# why casting does not change isa pointer

Tags: objective-c

```
id a = self->isa;
id b = ((NSObject*)self)->isa;
```

a and b holds same value.

Now given isa pointer is same, why does

```
[(Animal*)Person speakEnglish];
```

gives error? I thought casting will change isa pointer because if I cast a child class to it's parent class, I can not invoke the child's method anymore, and method invoke search is based on isa pointer.

I am interested to know how does method selector implemented, so that even isa pointer of an instance points to Person, If I call the Person's method of the instance, I will get an error.

Comment: Are you talking about run time errors or compiler errors / warnings? Casting doesn't do anything except give information to the compiler.

Comment: casting has nothing to do with isa. also normally isa cannot/shouldn't be modified (unless you know what you are doing). Objective-C message dispatch is done at runtime, unlike C++, where non-virtual function dispatch are done at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Animal` has no method `-speakEnglish`, but the original class of `Person` has.

Then, you get a compiler error, since the method is no declared. Please note, that (as @jrturton and @xlc0212 has mentioned) the compiler does not know anything about the runtime.

It may be possible that the object (at runtime) has a selector that can be called:

```
 [(Animal*)Person performSelector: @selector(speakEnglish)];
```

This uses runtime data. More precisely, it checks if a method implementation is connected with this selector and calls this implementation.

However, there is no way the compiler can know since the compiler relies on static type information. Thus, you should provide the proper type information. But you do the opposite: you throw away the correct type.

Comment: Animal is a class, so shouldn't be the method `+speakEnglish`?

Comment: @jaume: no, unless you really want the class object (not an object instance of the class) to perform the method. The point is that against the claim of the OP casting has nothing to do with `isa`; it is a matter of static types.

Comment: I first thought the OP was asking why casting class `Person` to its parent class `Animal` failed, as `Person` is capitalized and thus by convention a class. Now I think the OP probably means `[(Animal *)person speakEnglish]`, where `person` is an instance of class `Person`. In any case, as you say, it has nothing to do with `isa`.